# Is it possible to replace Lighthouse by custom tracking solution for large room scale VR for existing Steam games?

Tags: steam

Is it possible to replace SteamVR Lighthouse system by OptiTrack or use both OptiTrack and Lighthouse to create a large room scale VR ( 20 x 20 meters) for existing SteamVR games like PayDay 2? Or is it only possible to use OptiTrack is to create new games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My company has done some research on this and it is working quite well: https://vimeo.com/222442433

We made a SteamVR driver that replaces the original Lighthouse driver and adds Optitrack (or other) tracking data. We have some more information here: https://www.lp-research.com/vr-large-room-scale-tracking/

I can't provide too many details as we are also using this commercially, but at least you can see that in general there is a solution for this problem using the method mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine to wait. Wait for Vive Pro with Tracking 2.0 10x10 prommised, evem more in real life.

What about Microsoft HMD and inside out tracking, they seams to be unlimited :)

Comment: It's required to have at least 20 x 20, but why you think that Vive Pro will cover more than 10 x 10 in real life?

Comment: Didn't tested it, but it's prommising, as valve said there will be opttion to add more lightouses. Did you considered to use Samsung Oddysey then?

Comment: WMR still doesn't have anything like Vive Tracker for custom objects. This is the main reason why WMR doesn't work for me out of the box.

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no easy solution for you right now. Only working soolution for areas like this is based on vision systems. as you mentioned optitrack would be a good try. If you want to mix steamVR tracking with optitrack you would need write own custom driver. I assume optitrack provides SDK. But mixing 2 sdk's will allways be messy :)